# Make three.js script fixed in a scrollable page

Tags: javascript, css, html, three.js, 3d

I have a scrollable page and I wonder how do I make the 3d model (using three.js) have a fixed position so like have it as a background while the rest scrolls normally. Is there any way I could use css with the 3D model or anything I can add to my script to acheive this.

Heres the website right now.
trhidouan309.barzalou.com/Barzalou/personnelle.html

Btw I know my 3D model isnt close to be done.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example here of what you tried? Links change over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to (a) set the canvas that is rendering the three.js model to 'position: fixed' and then position it how you would like it on the page, and then (b) give the menu a positive z-index so it will be seen on top of the canvas.

Check out this code snippet for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/shawnoakley/s8a1ex9d/13/

Example CSS:

```
canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:-20px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}


ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked!